# How to remove points in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point

I have way points of my field work, but some of points I saved are not related to my project.

How can i remove them in QGIS?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! Please *edit* your question and include additonal information about: 1) your data - is it a shapefile, database, etc.; 2) What you have tried so far and what the desired outcome is. 3) It never hurts to include the version of qgis you are using. You can also take the [**tour**](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) to get some helpful pointers on asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

there are as always some options for the points you dont want: filter them out by a query, or what you probably are looking for edit them.

For edits you must make the layer active in the TOC and then start the editing by pushing the yellow pencil icon. Further select the points you want to edit out and delete them with "delete selected".

This process may be done both from the map window and frm the attribute table. Please also see for [this example](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html). Look for the chapter called "Digitizing an existing layer"

Good luck!